# How to use a Jinja variable inside of sphinx ref directive or head tag?

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx

I'm using sphinx and auto-summary to create my documentation. However, for each module a I want to generate customized list of references. However, to do that, I need to pass the objname to ref directive.  How can I achieve that?

```
{{ fullname | escape | underline}}

.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}

   Items
   -----
   {% block classestab %}
   {% if classes %}
   {% for objname in classes %}
      - :ref:` {{objname}} <{{objname}}>`_  // doesn't work
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```

I've also trying to use a jinja variable to create headings for my documentation. However I don't know to achieve this. The code below will not work of course

```
{% block table %}
   {% if classes %}
   {% for objname in classes %}
      {{objname}}
      ===========
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```